# Duda sobre relacion de BD entre la tabla cestas y tabla productos

Tags: base-de-datos, spring-boot, jpa, modelorelacional

Buenas estoy haciendo una tienda online y estoy usando Spring para desarrollar el backend.

Mis tablas son :

- Usuarios
- Productos
- Cestas
- Historial

Estoy ahora desarrollando el `@Entity` de **Cestas** y me da la siguiente duda:

A ver un usuario tiene una cesta y una cesta puede tener un producto de cada tipo ya uqe si tiene mas lo que hara sera aumentar la cantidad y ya esta. Por tanto mi duda es la siguiente :

**Cesta.java**

```
package com.crn.tienda.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cestas")
public class Cesta implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "usuario_id")
    @OneToOne
    private Usuario  usuario;

    @Column(name = "producto_id")
    @OneToOne
    private Producto producto;

    @Column(name = "cantidad")
    private int cantidad;



}
```

Que relacion seria entre **cesta** y **productos** , es que desde como se ve en Spring me esta liando un poco. 
Seria `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToMany`, ... ?

**DIAGRAMA ER**

[image: Model ER]

Comment: El problema no es el JPA de Spring, si no el origen que es tu ER (Entidad Relación), donde venga explicado exactamente como tienes relacionado Cesta, Usuario y Producto, de entrada por lo que veo, probablemente tengas una relación uno a uno de cesta a producto, lo que no te permitirá mas que tener un id_producto por un id_cesta, podrías editar la pregunta y colocar tu diagrama entidad relación. Saludos

Comment: De acuerdo. Pregunta editada. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias, dos cosa  haces el mapeo manual? o con alguna herramienta como las de Eclipse?, y la segunda, tendrías problemas de usar claves puestas?

Comment: El mapeo es manual si, uso VSCODE , lo de claves puestas no se a que te refieres.

Comment: Perdón me equivoque son claves compuestas, te haré un ejemplo para que te des una idea de como podría implementarse, solo termino unas cosas jaja. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Diagrama Entidad Relación Propuesto]

Normalmente las tablas (o entidades se nombran en singular), como ves en el diagrama ER que te envío. Tienes un usuario, este usuario hará una cesta (imagino que la cesta es como un carrito de compras), aquí la clave primaria son la combinación del producto y el usuario. Esta tabla se podría decir que será solo para guardar los productos antes de comprarlos.

Una vez que el usuario decida comprar, generas un id_compra de compra con su fecha y su folio, y lo registras en la tabla de historial_compra, después de esto vuelcas todos los productos de las cesta a historial_compra_producto. Con la implementación de las claves compuestas te obligas a tener registros previos con cierta trazabilidad.

Lo puedes mapear y te hará las relaciones uno a muchos, no se si estés desplegando en algún servidor Middleware o algo, pero a veces hay que hacer un par de ajustes al JPA, pero eso ya lo puedes abrir en otra pregunta y te ayudo.

Saludos!